# React Route - The problem with clicking on links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a strange problem I am using a sidebar the user can go to the desired tab by clicking on a specific link it looks like this

[image]

And today I noticed that I can shorten my code using a certain option, now I will explain everything.

At the moment, the structure of my project looks like this

**SideBarItems.js**

```
const SidebarItems = [
    { CourseTopic: "Introduction" },
    "Introduction",
    "Creating Your First Javascript",
    "Comments",
    "Let",
    "Variables",
    "Data Types",
].map((itemName) => {
    if (typeof itemName === "string") {
        return {
            name: itemName,
            CourseTopic: itemName.CourseTopic || "",
            route: `/${itemName}`,
        };
    } else {
        return {
            name: itemName.name,
            CourseTopic: itemName.CourseTopic,
            route: `/${itemName.names}`,
        };
    }
});

export default SidebarItems;
```

**Routes.js**

```
function RoutesPage(props) {
    const {path} = props.path;
    const {location} = props.location.pathname;

    const routes = [
    {path: `${path}/Introduction`, component: () => <Introduction SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Creating Your First Javascript`, component: () => <CreatingFirstJS SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Comments`, component: () => <Comments SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Let`, component: () => <Let SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Variables`, component: () => <Variables SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Data Types`, component: () => <DataTypes SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Objects`, component: () => <Objects SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Events`, component: () => <Events SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Strings`, component: () => <Strings SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/String Methods`, component: () => <StringMethods SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: `${path}/Intro to ES6`, component: () => <Intro SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    ];

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, index) => (
                    <Route
                        key={index}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact={route.exact}
                        component={route.component}
                    />
                ))}
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default RoutesPage;
```

Please pay attention to `Path`, `Path` chronizes the string "`Lesson`" then I assign the string `Introduction`, `Comments`, Let and so on, that is, it turns out "`Lesson/Let`" or "`Lesson/Introduction`" and so on and everything works fine for me. I can follow the links and everything is great.

But today I noticed that it is not necessary to manually write the paths, since I already have all the paths stored inside the `location`, here is the picture.

[image]

And of course I decided to use `pathname` from `location` I replaced my code appropriately

```
const {pathname} = props.location.pathname;

const routes = [
    {path: pathname, component: () => <Introduction SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: pathname, component: () => <CreatingFirstJS SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
    {path: pathname, component: () => <Comments SideBarThemeValue={SideBarThemeValue} AlertStyleBG={AlertStyleBG}/>},
];
```

And after that, when I try to follow the links, my url changes, that is, the url works, but the content is not displayed and I cannot understand this reason.

Comment: the location.pathname changes when you go into a path, so wouldn't the paths change from `/Lesson/Comments` to `/Lesson/Comments/Lesson/Comments` which would make none of your routes match? you can't change the pathname of the routes based on the current location then they will never match

Comment: You can't use `pathname` in that way. The `pathname` you are seeing in the picture gets generated (takes that form) after React Router renders a path. So the answer is simply: "Revert back your changes".